# Cannot import Firebase or FirebaseDatabase into multiple classes in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have installed Firebase and FirebaseDatabase into my project using `CocoaPods` as they describe on the site. On one ViewController I have FirebaseDatabase imported and everything seems to fine there, but when I try to import FirebaseDatabase onto another class, it starts to glitch and throw compiler errors in both classes.

For example, if I have FirebaseDatabase imported **only** to `ViewController1`, everything works fine:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    let classRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("SomeClass")
    ...
}
```

But if I import it to 1 other class or more, with the same code, it throws errors like:
`Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRDatabase'`
and on other types or functions that have to do with FirebaseDatabase.
Sometimes it will also throw: `Command failed to due signal: Segmentation fault: 11`
If i try to remove the import statement from the other class it will still glitch for some time and I'd have to build the project a couple of times until it builds successfully.

Another thing I have noticed is that when I try to import the Firebase Modules, If I have already imported them once in some other class, the modules will be displayed with a strikethrough, like in here: (if it matters)
[image]

I have already tried to reinstall the pods and clean the `DerivedData` folder but nothing helps.
What could be the problem?

Comment: If you just import Firebase, instead of the database specifically it should work the same. Firebase is the only import you should need.

Comment: @SeanRobinson159 I've tried that too, doesn't seem to work for me..

Comment: What's your Podfile look like? Just reaching here as that's an odd issue.

Comment: @Mitley you can try only using import Firebase in both places. In the first view controller you can leave the same, in the second view controller that starts breaking Xcode, reference the database through the FIRApp instead of FIRDatabase directly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to resolve?

Comment: I have the same problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you created the file (cocoa touch / etc.) while you were working in the xcworkspace. If you are working in the regular xcodeproj, then the cocoapod wont translate

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you fixed the issue, but if not try this:

Make sure the second view controller, in your case I presume viewcontroller2, only target membership is the "App" itself (you can find this in the right utility bar).

In other words, when you add a new file of typer "Cocoa Touch class" - just after the step where it asks you to pick name for you class, subclass and language - it asks you where you want to save it and who you want to target (you have usually 3 checkboxes, with only your Application selected - if it is leave this way don't check anything else); your "app', "app"Tests, and "app"UITests. Make sure that only your "app" as targeted member and nothing else.

Hope that helps